# MDX as Calculated Member in SSAS Cube

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube-script

I have a FactBudget per sales region with fields `[Budget SalesRegion]` and `[Sales Region]`. In the dimension `DimCustomer` I have the fields `[Sales Region]` and `[Customer Type]`.

The relation between `FactBudget` and `DimCustomer` is defined only on the `[Sales Region]`.

I have a rather simple `mdx` statement that filters the `[Sales Region]` of the `DimCustomer` for a certain `[Customer Type]`. With the returned [Sales Region] I select the correspondent [Budget SalesRegion]:

```
SELECT 
   (
   FILTER(
      [Kunde].[Sales Region].members
     ,[Kunde].[Customer Type].CURRENTMEMBER
          =[Kunde].[Customer Type].[All].[Direct Sales]
    )
   ,[Measures].[Budget SalesRegion]
   ) ON 0,
   [Kunde].[Customer Type].[All].[Direct Sales] ON 1
FROM [BI_DWH];
```

How can I translate this statement into an Calculated Member in the `SSAS cube` so that the selected [Customer Type] in a slicer filters the statement accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
SELECT 
   (
   FILTER(
      [Kunde].[Sales Region].members
     ,[Kunde].[Customer Type].CURRENTMEMBER
          =[Kunde].[Customer Type].[All].[Direct Sales]
    )
   ,[Measures].[Budget SalesRegion]
   ) ON 0,
   [Kunde].[Customer Type].[All].[Direct Sales] ON 1
FROM [BI_DWH];
```

Is the same as this:

```
SELECT 
   [Measures].[Budget SalesRegion] ON 0,
   [Kunde].[Customer Type].[All].[Direct Sales] ON 1
FROM [BI_DWH];
```

Or if you want to use the slicer axis:

```
SELECT 
   [Measures].[Budget SalesRegion] ON 0
FROM [BI_DWH]
WHERE [Kunde].[Customer Type].[All].[Direct Sales];
```

Now it is simplified I do not understand what you question is?

Comment: No, it's not the same. As stated in my question, the `[Budget SalesRegion]` is only related to `[Kunde]` by the field `[Sales Region]`. With your proposed statement, I just get the total of `[Budget SalesRegion]`. There is not relation between the `[Budget SalesRegion]` and `[Kunde].[Customer Type]`.
I need to filter `[Kunde]` by `[Customer Type]`, get the `[Sales Region]` from this selection, and then get my `[Budget SalesRegion]` from the selected `[Sales Regions]`.